# Can 'fread' be used more than one time?

Tags: php

```
<?php
   $myFile="php01.txt";
   $fh=fopen($myFile, 'r');
   $theData02=fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
   $theData03=fread($fh, 20);
   fclose($fh);
   echo $theData02;
   echo $theData03;
?>
```

This is the code that I'm experimenting.
I tried using fread twice, and found out that only the first one is working.
I cannot use fread twice? If I want to print the whole string and the part of it, what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

First one reads whole data and puts pointer at the end of file. So, second one have nothing to read...

Try with

```
$theData02 = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fseek($fh, 0);
$theData03 = fread($fh, 20);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`fread()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fread.php) reads unless the internal file pointer reaches the end of the file. You are reaching the end of the file with this line:

```
$theData02=fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
```

Then you are trying to read again:

```
$theData03=fread($fh, 20);
```

but what? You have already read until the end.

---

If you want to read again, from the beginning of the file (or somewhere in the middle of the file), you need to modify the file pointer using [`fseek()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fseek.php):

```
fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET); // beginning of the file
fseek($fh, $offset, SEEK_SET); // somewhere in the middle of the file. 

// Note: SEEK_SET is the default value, I've just passed it for 
// educational purposes.
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP.NET fread()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

> Reading stops as soon as one of the following conditions is met:
>
> ...
>
> EOF (end of file) is reached

```
$theData02=fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
```

You already read all the file (with filesize), so the reading stops.

The following code will do what you want :

```
<?php
   $myFile="php01.txt";
   $fh=fopen($myFile, 'r');
   $theData02=fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
   $theData03=substr($theData02, 0, 20); // <= modification here, it reads 20 letters from the start of $theData02
   fclose($fh);
   echo $theData02;
   echo $theData03;
?>
```